# How to correct unbalanced parenthesis error in regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am learning regular expression through Al Sweigart's automate the boring stuff course on udemy, lesson 29. I get an error saying "unbalanced parenthesis at position 414 (line 12, column 1)"

The code is meant to pull phone numbers and email addresses using regular expression.

I have tried counting the parenthesis and taking the top and bottom parenthesis out for the email regex.

```
#! python3

import re, pyperclip

# Done - TODO: create a regex object for phone numbers
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''
# Types of number 415-555-0000, 555-0000, (415) 555-0000, 555-0000 ext 12345,
# ext. 12345, x12345
(
((\d\d\d) | (\(\d\d\d\)))?            # area code (optional)
(\s|-)            # first separator
\d\d\d            # first 3 digits
-            # separator
\d\d\d\d            # last 4 digits
((ext(\.)?\s)|x)           # extension word part (optional)
(\d{2,5}))?             # extension number part (optional)
)
''', re.VERBOSE)

# TODO: Create a regex for email addresses
emailRegex = re.compile (r'''
# some.+_thing@(\d{2,5}))?.com

[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+         # name part - created non default regular   expression class
# to capture any character a-z lowercase, A-Z upper case, numbers 0-9, characters _.+
@        # @ symbol
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+        # domain name part

''', re.VERBOSE)

# TODO: Get the text off the clipboard
text = pyperclip.paste()

# TODO: Extract the email/phone from this text
extractedPhone = phoneRegex.findall(text) # creates one string for each group ()
# Make sure desired regex is all in one group ()
extractedEmail = emailRegex.findall(text)

print (extractedPhone)# temporary print function to see if code works
print (extractedEmail)
```

Gives this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users*\Desktop\Education\computer science\automate the boring   stuff\programs\lesson 29 phone and email regex.py", line 18,
>   in 
>       ''', re.VERBOSE)
>        File "C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line
>   234, in compile
>         return _compile(pattern, flags)
>        File "C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line
>   286, in _compile
>         p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
>        File "C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\sre_compile.py",
>   line 764, in compile
>         p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
>        File "C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py",
>   line 944, in parse
>        raise source.error("unbalanced parenthesis")
>        re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 414 (line 12, column 1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix this line `(\d{2,5}))? # extension number part (optional)`. Clearly it needs to either add/remove a parenthesis.

Changing that line to `(\d{2,5})?` will fix the `unbalanced parenthesis` error.

Comment: @neoraiden Let me know if this change worked properly for you. Thanks

Comment: It corrected the parenthesis error thanks, but the phone number section of the regular expression is not finding the numbers, so I am now looking through trying to solve that issue.

Comment: I was originally missing a parentheses on line 15 column 1 # extension word part at the beginning which I needed for the numbers regex to work and to balance the parenthesis.

Comment: I was originally missing a parentheses on line 15 column 1 # extension word part at the beginning which I needed for the numbers regex to work and to balance the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the unbalance that will
probably give you an idea how to fix it.

```
     # Types of number 415-555-0000, 555-0000, (415) 555-0000, 555-0000 ext 12345,
     # ext. 12345, x12345
     (                             # (1 start)
          (                             # (2 start), area code (optional)
               ( \d\d\d )                    # (3)
            |  ( \( \d\d\d \) )              # (4)
          )?                            # (2 end)
          ( \s | - )                    # (5), first separator
          \d\d\d                        # first 3 digits
          -                             # separator
          \d\d\d\d                      # last 4 digits
          (                             # (6 start), extension word part (optional)
               (                             # (7 start)
                    ext
                    ( \. )?                       # (8)
                    \s
               )                             # (7 end)
            |  x
          )                             # (6 end)
          ( \d{2,5} )                   # (9), extension number part (optional)
     )?                            # (1 end)
=    )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'
```